# VideoJs Streaming Error for loading player

Tags: video-streaming, video.js

I am using videojs in website. If video is not streaming everything is ok and work, but when i try to load the video by streaming i catch many error `video.js:142 VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` and `videojs-http-streaming.min.js:2510 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` and i do not know why ... i worked by example https://videojs.github.io/http-streaming/ , but do not work.
here is my code:

```
 <video-js id="example-video" class="vjs-default-skin" width=960 height=400 controls>
      <source
        src="https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8"
        type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video-js>                                                  
    <script src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web') ?>/js/videojs/video.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web') ?>/js/videojs/videojs-http-streaming.min.js"></script>
    <script>                                                    
            var player = videojs('example-video');
            player.play();
    </script>
```

Comment: Try changing your 'video-js' element tags to just 'video' tags.  Also, try moving your two 'script' tagged lines (that are importing the support code) UP ABOVE the opening 'video' tag. (Best HTML practices recommend putting imported javascript up in the 'header' tagged section.)

Comment: I tried but nothing is change ... errors are the same ...